# Calculate risk-neutral probability

Tags: probability, finance

Consider a two-step binomial model in which at each step the share price either doubles, with probability $p ∈ (0, 1)$, or halves, with probability $1 − p ∈ (0, 1)$. Initially the price is $S_0 = 4$. Assume each step takes one unit of time and that over one unit of time the risk-free rate is $r = \log(5/4)$.

Calculate the risk-neutral probability of an up-move.

Well, I am in the very beginning of my course and the notion of "risk-neutral probability" was not fully developed yet. I tried to do some calculations, but it seems to me that I need p to calculate such probability.

Can someone please help me by clarifying the concept and showing beginning of the right path?

Comment: Could you define risk-free rate and risk-neutral probability?

Comment: I think you have got have your answer by Alborz. If you have no more questions accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the interest rate is compounded continuously, the cost of the investment must equal the (present-time value) expected value of the payoff of that investment. If this weren't the case, then we would have arbitrage (non risk-neutral).

Let $P$ be the payoff of the investment of purchasing $1$ unit of the stock price at initial time $0$. The cost of this investment is then just $S_0$.

Then $$E[PV[P]] = S_0$$

So $$e^{-r}E[P]=S_0$$

And $E[P]=2S_0*P(S_1=2S_0) + \tfrac12S_0*P(S_1=\tfrac12S_0)=2S_0p+\tfrac12S_0(1-p)$. Thus, $$E[P]=S_0e^r$$
$$2S_0p+\tfrac12S_0(1-p)=S_0e^r$$
Do some algebra, with using $r=log(\tfrac54)$, to get $$p=\tfrac12$$
Which makes sense intuitively.

Comment: Can you please clarify the meaning of V[P]?

Comment: I mean, I don't exactly understand the meaning of $[[]]$

Comment: PV meaning present value (not P*V). So E[PV[P]] means E[present value of P] or expectation of present value of P

Comment: Oh, now it is more clear, thanks